# Multiple applications under one website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have three applications(App1,App2,APP3) hosted under one website(Default Website) in IIS. I have created three DNS(http://website1.com, http://website2.com, http://website3.com) which will point to this IP address.  Is it possible to show Application 1(app1) when the incoming request is http://website1.com , Application 2(app2) when the incoming request is http://website2.com and Application 3(app3) when the incoming request is http://website3.com

Comment: If you're using the same IP for all three sites, you will need to use host headers.

Comment: How to add an host header to the application which is hosted under a website?

Comment: see my answer below, with a link on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the same IP address for all three sites, you will need to configure host headers within IIS

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: The applications are hosted under the same website. I can set the host header at the website level. Can I set  it at application level?

Comment: That's not really the ideal set up for wanting three root web applications using the same IP address. Is there a specific reason why you need to set it up this way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes since this is a redirect, you can see for the `referer` Request agent to look into which of the website was visited before you got redirected here. Using these headers you will be able to get the website from where he is coming, website1 website2 or website3 and show the application you want to show there.

In the request headers below, see the `referer` as last page from where the user (I; in this case) came from to this page.

[image]

In ASP.NET you can that value as,

```
var previousPage = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: Can you explain more on the "show the application you want to show there" part? I'm curious where you're headed with this.